# how to get value from dropdown using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to get a select value from a dropdown using angular.js

angular code:

```
var sbAdmin2 = angular.module('sbAdmin2',[]);
sbAdmin2.controller('dropdownCtrl', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.chnagecustomer= function() {
        $scope.value=$scope.dropdown;
        console.log($scope.value);
    };
});
```

html code:

```
<select 
  ng-controller="dropdownCtrl" 
  class="form-control" 
  ng-change="chnagecustomer()" 
  ng-model="selectedPerson" 
  id="p_client_main" 
  name="p_client_main" 
  tabindex="2">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

- in jquery `.val()` would work to get dropdown value which is selected
- but I need to know the angular way.
- I'm new in angular. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always got selected value in ng-model (`selectedperson` in your code)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.change = function () {
    alert($scope.value);
  }
})
```

simple example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BEmcCWnmxRJvcGrM1Btp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you're accessing the model's value in your change function. Edit that function to look like this:

```
$scope.chnagecustomer= function() {
  $scope.value = $scope.selectedPerson;
  console.log($scope.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$scope.value=$scope.selectedPerson` the value of your dropdown list should be the model.

Answer (score 0):

try using {$scope.value=$scope.selectedPerson;} as thats your model variable